# Chaos Bound in BCFT

Tags: conformal-field-theory, chaos-theory

What is the Chaos bound in boundary conformal field theory (In 2d or in higher dimension)? can one derive much restricted bound in these settings?

Comment: Does the question [Bound on Quantum Chaos](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/453733/75633) answer your question?

Comment: The question was "can one derive much restricted bound in these settings". I don't know whether stricter bound exist or not.